# jQuery animations in callback not working

Tags: jquery

Okay, so I'd like to animate footprints walking across my webpage.

I fade in one foot, then the other, then fade out the first and fade in a third one and so on. However, in my second nested callback (where I'd like to fade out the first footprint) animation functions (I tried .fadeIn() and .animate() ) won't work, while .hide() does work. How come?

http://jsfiddle.net/YEfJR/9/

Here's a simplified version of the code:

HTML

```
<div id="one">1</div>
<div id="two">2</div>
<div id="three">3</div>
```

CSS

```
#one, #two, #three {
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px; 
    position: fixed; 
    display: none; 
    background: #af0;
}
```

jQuery

```
$("#start").click( function(){ 
    $g1x = 0;
    $g1y = 0;
    $g2x = 100;
    $g2y = 100;

    $("#one").css({"bottom": $g1y+"px", "left": $g1x+"px"}).fadeIn(1000).delay(1000, function() {
        $("#two").css({"bottom": $g2y+"px", "left": $g2x+"px"}).fadeIn(1000).delay(1000, function() {
             $("#one").fadeOut(1000);
        });
    });
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the complete callback as the second argument to [.fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadein)

```
$("#start").click( function(){ 
    $g1x = 0;
    $g1y = 0;
    $g2x = 100;
    $g2y = 100;

    $("#one").css({"bottom": $g1y+"px", "left": $g1x+"px"}).fadeIn(1000, function() {
        $("#two").css({"bottom": $g2y+"px", "left": $g2x+"px"}).fadeIn(1000, function() {
             $("#one").fadeOut(1000);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Works! Thank you. (I need a delay, so I just put .delay() before .fadeIn() )